# Using map function to transform an item in a list

Tags: kotlin

```
Kotlin 1.4.21
```

I have a list of Products and I want to transform the price to a formatted string. However, the price doesn't change to the formatted one.

i.e.

```
orginal price: 1658

expected: "1,658.00"

actual: 1658
```

This is the class structure

```
data class Product(
    val productName: String,
    val price: Double)
```

Here I am using my list of projects and I want to transform the price.

```
listOfProjects.map {
    it.price.toAmount(2) // extension function that formats to 2 decimal places and converts to a string
}

if (listOfProjects.isNotEmpty()) {
    // Do something with the list. However, the price hasn't changed
}
```

Comment: The type of a property cannot be changed. You would need a distinct class to represent a Product with the price represented as a String. Or you can write an extension property for this class to produce the formatted price on demand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably are expecting it to perform `in-place` formatting. Maybe if you assign an output variable you would be able to get it:

```kotlin
val result = listOfProjects.map { it.price.toAmount(2) }
println(result)
```

Or if you add a `val formattedPrice: String` property on the `Project` class you can define it like this:

```kotlin
val formattedPrice: String = price.toAmount(2)
```

and then you can use this property in a `toString()` method for example.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But the new list will only return a list of price: i.e. `List<String>` as price is now a string. Howerver, I want to have a `List<Product>` that will contain the name and the formatted price.

I can't modifiy class `Product` with another `formattedPrice`

Comment: @ant2009 I edited my comment to include a field `formattedPrice` on your project of type `String`. Maybe you can use this property for your purpose

Comment: Just a bit late. I answered that in my previous comment :). Is there anyway to use `in-place` and return a list of products with the formatted price?

Comment: Short answer is no. First, your price is `Double`, so you can't make it `String`; second, your property is `val` so it cannot be reassigned. You will have to create a new wrapper class, maybe `ProductFormatted` where you have such a field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried :

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
val dec = DecimalFormat("###.###,##")
```

Comment: The problem is that the price doesn't change after performing the mapping operation. Even if I do something like this: `it.price.toString() + " deal"` there is no change.